# Jquery OOP model prevent default then call base handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I use jquery mobile; is it possible to set an onclick event handler that does something but then still trigger the base event handler set by jqm.

Example:

```
$("mybutton").bind("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          //... do something custom...
          e.callBasicEvent
});
```

or something like that

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: ? jqm's handler will trigger without you doing anything. If it's attached before yours, it has already executed when your handler is called.

Comment: I need to do that because I want to first load a screen and only then slide to it, otherwise when I click the first time it does not slide since the screen is not yet loaded. How can I in the worst case take control and trigger the jqm slide transition myself? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 $("mybutton").click( function(e){        
    var clicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');   

     if (clicked == false) {

        //... do something custom...

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $(this).click();            
     }
 });
```